# In Meteor how can I publish processed results of a find query as a cursor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, underscore.js, meteor-publications

I'm building a simple messaging app with Meteor.  The section I'm struggling with in **unread messages**.  I would like to return a list, showing the **username** (I'm not concerned about this, please don't focus on this aspect, around reactive joins/ composites etc ) and **the latest message from that user**   What I need to return therefore, in the publish function below, is the newest unread messages, **BUT** obviously only one from each unique user id.

to do this im trying to manipulate the results of a find query in my publish method, but I'm unclear as to how to manipulate the document set without breaking the reactivity as I've shown in currently in the code below, this is what i've got so far :

```
Meteor.publish('unreadmessages', function() {

    if (!this.userId) {
        throw new Meteor.Error('denied', 'not-authorized');
    }

    var messageQuery, messages, userGroupQuery, userGroups;

    var self        = this;
    var user        = Meteor.users.findOne(self.userId);
    var userIdArr   = [self.userId]; // for use where queries require an array
    var contacts    = user.contacts;

    // get groups
    userGroupQuery  = Groups.find({
        $or : [
            { owner   : self.userId },
            { members : self.userId }
        ]
    }, { // Projection to only return the _id field
            fields : { _id:1 }
        }
    );

    userGroups = _.pluck(userGroupQuery.fetch(), '_id'); // create an array of id's

    messages = Messages.find({
        $or : [
            {
                $and : [
                    { participant : self.userId },
                    { userId : { $in : contacts } },
                    { readBy : { $nin : userIdArr } }
                ]
            },
            {
                $and : [
                    { groupId : { $in : userGroups } },
                    { readBy  : { $nin : userIdArr } }
                ]
            },
        ]
    });

     // TODO : also handle groups here
    uniqueMessages = _.uniq(messages.fetch(), function(msg) {
        return msg.userId;
    });

    return uniqueMessages; // obviously an array and not a cursor - meteor errors out.

});
```

i realize that my underscore function is of course working with, and indeed returning, an array rather than the reactive cursor i need.  i know one solution would be to simply pluck the message ids and then run another .find on messages, but is there another / better / more efficient / more natural way to return a cursor with the result set i'm looking for?

Comment: What you have written is not reactive so maybe you really just want a Meteor.method.  A method can return an array to the client.

Comment: Also, Messages.find() will already return a set of unique messages.  To understand why you are calling _.uniq it would be helpful to show  some example docs from Messages.

Comment: I'm clear that what i have now is not reactive, but i'd like it to return a cursor that is, so definitely after a publish function i think, and secondly, to explain i'm looking to return the latest unread message for each of the users contacts or groups. without the _uniq (or something similar) i get all of the unread messages.

Comment: Note I've added a working solution below, but I don't feel like this is the ideal approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres the final working code.  This does return a cursor as basically what I'm doing is taking the results from multiple queries / modifications and pumping a set of id's into the final .find query.

```
Meteor.publish('unreads', function() {
    if (!this.userId) {
        throw new Meteor.Error('denied', 'not-authorized');
    }

    // setup some vars
    var messageQuery,
        messages,
        userGroupQuery,
        userGroups,
        uniqeMsgIds;
    var self        = this;
    var user        = Meteor.users.findOne(self.userId);
    var userIdArr   = [self.userId]; // for use where queries require an array
    var contacts    = user.contacts;

    // get groups
    userGroupQuery  = Groups.find({
        $or : [
            { owner : self.userId },
            { members : self.userId }
        ]
    }, { // Projection to only return the _id field
            fields : { _id:1 }
        }
    );

    // create an array of group id's that belong to the user.
    userGroups = _.pluck(userGroupQuery.fetch(), '_id');

    messages = Messages.find({
        $or : [
            {  // unread direct messages
                $and : [
                    { participant : self.userId },
                    { userId : { $in : contacts } },
                    { readBy : { $nin : userIdArr } }
                ]
            },
            {  // unread group messages
                $and : [
                    { groupId : { $in : userGroups } },
                    { readBy : { $nin : userIdArr } }
                ]
            },
        ]
    }, { sort : { // put newest messages first
            time : -1
        }
    });

     // returns an array of unique documents based on userId or groupId
    uniqueMessages = _.uniq(messages.fetch(), function(msg) {
        if (msg.groupId) {
            return msg.groupId;
        }
        return msg.userId;
    });

    /*  Get the id's of all the latest unread messages
    (one per user or group) */
    uniqeMsgIds = _.pluck(uniqueMessages, '_id');

    /*  finally publish a reactive cursor containing
    one unread message(latest) for each user/group */
    return Messages.find({
        _id : { $in : uniqeMsgIds }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [observeChanges](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe_changes) and makes this reactive. On the `added`, you can add fields. I'm using this amazing package: [meteor-publish-composite](https://github.com/englue/meteor-publish-composite), It saves you time.

Use pagination, otherwise you won't enjoy the performance.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm specifically trying to avoid a few of the convenience packages on my first app (or at least its first iteration) to really dig into Meteor and learn as much as i can.  Could you possibly add an example of how you would alter my publish function to use `observeChanges` and `added` ?

Comment: after having a look at observerChanges and meteor publish composite, I'm not convinced you understand the question I'm asking, or maybe I don't understand your answer, I'm not looking to publish a composite, I'm adding a description of the expected result set above.

Answer (score 0):

The following code does publish a reactive cursor and is a viable solution, but I suppose the crux of my question is if there is a better  way to manipulate the result set of of the second last `Messages.find`  to still publish a reactive cursor (I'm thinking along the lines o the cursor.forEach or .map but I'm not sure how to approach this).

Basically  - **is there a better way to do this :**

```
Meteor.publish('unreads', function() {
    if (!this.userId) {
        throw new Meteor.Error('denied', 'not-authorized');
    }

    // setup some vars
    var messageQuery, messages, userGroupQuery, userGroups, uniqeMsgIds;
    var self        = this;
    var user        = Meteor.users.findOne(self.userId);
    var userIdArr   = [self.userId]; // for use where queries require an array
    var contacts    = user.contacts;

    // get groups
    userGroupQuery  = Groups.find({
        $or : [
            { owner   : self.userId },
            { members : self.userId }
        ]
    }, { // Projection to only return the _id field
            fields : { _id:1 }
        }
    );

    // create an array of group id's that belong to the user.
    userGroups = _.pluck(userGroupQuery.fetch(), '_id');

    messages = Messages.find({
        $or : [
            {  // unread direct messages
                $and : [
                    { participant : self.userId },
                    { userId      : { $in : contacts } },
                    { readBy      : { $nin : userIdArr } }
                ]
            },
            {  // unread group messages
                $and : [
                    { groupId : { $in : userGroups } },
                    { readBy  : { $nin : userIdArr } }
                ]
            },
        ]
    }, { sort : { // put newest messages first
            time : -1
        }
    });

     // returns an array of unique documents based on userId or groupId
    uniqueMessages = _.uniq(messages.fetch(), function(msg) {
        if (msg.groupId) {
            return msg.groupId;
        }
        return msg.userId;
    });

    // Get the id's of all the latest unread messages (one per user or group)
    uniqeMsgIds = _.pluck(uniqueMessages, '_id');

    // finally publish a reactive cursor containing one unread message(latest) for each user/group
    return Messages.find({
        _id : { $in : uniqeMsgIds };
    });

});
```

Comment: after finding this discussion http://meta.telesc.pe/posts/y4piwYfDhzJMPpHdb  i feel like this is the right way to go about it.